# Do you store planning documents in source control? If so, where?

Tags: svn, version-control, project-planning

I'm working on a small, personal project and am using Subversion to manage the source code. I have a couple of small planning files - simple text documents explaining where I want to go with the project and some ideas worth keeping track of about what I've already done - that I think should be under source control as well.

What I don't know is where to put these documents. Should they be in a top level folder, i.e.

```
/project
   /branches
   /tags
   /trunk
   /planning (or /design or something else)
```

or if they should be somewhere in the trunk:

```
/project
   /trunk
      /private
         /planning
         /models
         /views
         /controllers
      /public
         /js
         /images
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the plan affects the whole project, in my humble opinion, it should be stored in a top-level directory.

Comment: That's what I was thinking. Updates would then be made from a separate working copy, out of band from normal source code updates.